# C ignores the return value

Tags: c, function, return

I am working with a big MPI project. In one of the files (let's call it as one.c) I have a function like this one:

```
#include two.h

void foo(){
  printf("the value is %f", bar(1));
}
```

Where in file two.h I have (apart from other function def):

```
double bar(int);
```

Finally, in file two.c I have (apart from other stuff):

```
static double a[2] = {0.0,4.0};

double bar(int temp){
   return a[temp];
}
```

From the above code I should obtain 4.0 but I obtain always 0.0, even if I just put:

```
 return 3.0;
```

I cannot understand the problem because even if in two.c I do:

```
double bar(int temp){
   printf("temp is %d", temp);
   return a[temp];
}
```

I obtain 1 for temp and a[1] returns also 4.0. So the problem is that is not connecting fine the value between files. Any idea?

**NOTE:** As I said, it is a BIG MPI project. I am not going to post here all the code because is not reasonable. I just add what I though it was necessary. Of course all is linked, otherwise I would not ask it. I am asking this because it is a very strange thing that I though some strange thing could scape from my knowledge. At the end, I have realised that if I call another double function in two.c, then, if I call again my foo function I obtain the good value but still I do not know why because as I said, bar was being recognised, temp was recognised, and a[temp] had the correct value.

**NOTE2:** I think that my problem was when doing make mpi. Maybe when saving the files or when I was doing the make, the date was not updated and at the end, files where not built again.

Comment: Also compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). I guess that you would have a warning, and that should be helpful.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Can't reproduce.

Comment: Is it possible the compiler doesn't know the route to two.h?

Comment: `#include two.h` won't compile, please post real code and best a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, we cannot debug this bug for you. The problem is not in the code you posted. Maybe undefined behaviour is involved here. Use a debugger, breakpoints etc.

Comment: `one.c` is missing `#include <stdio.h>`.  Better to post a complete compile-able minimal example.

Comment: "I should obtain 4.0 but I obtain always 0.0" --> How did you obtain the `0.0`, by what mechanism?  If it was via the `printf("the value is %f", bar(1));`, was the obtained output `"0.000000"`?  Using  `"%e"` is more useful as about 1/4 of all `double` print `0.00000` with `%f` while `%e` or `"%a"` will more likely report _interesting_ information.

Comment: Some systems have trouble if FP math only occurs inside `printf()` and friends as the FP library is not linked without other FP math _somewhere_.  Add some trivial `double` calculations to `main()`

Comment: As I wrote, after calling another function, now this function returns whatever has to return, even if I do not change %f per %e or %a. What is FP? Btw Michael, I can only do prints. I cannot find any tool to debug MPI projects.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#include "two.h"`.
Otherwise it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I make files one.c two.c, and two.h to your specification, add

main.c:

```
void foo();
imt main(){ foo(); }
```

compile them:

```
for c in *.c; do gcc $c -c; done
```

link them

```
gcc *.o
```

and run the result

```
./a.out
```

I get:

```
the value is 4.000000
```